The Rendered display method in sequencer doesn't render scene strips
The sequencer doesn't render scene strips in an animation if the display method is set to Rendered.

It previews scene strips and can render an image in this mode, but not animation.
This happens even in a default project with a fully reinstalled app. I had this problem initially, then it disappeared and I was able to render an animation with scene stripes using compositing, but now it has returned again.

The problem was only in rendering using Video Sequencer → View → Sequence Render Animation, not Render → Render Animation.

To me, this looks like the behavior that should be expected, as rendering via the View menu is a way to make Blender skip the rendering stage. Any reason why you have to render this way?

@pevinkinel No, there was no reason, I just thought that Render → Render Animation works only in the 3D Viewport and I didn't try to render using it in the scene where the sequence is.
